# Wordpress Stylesheet before <!DOCTYPE html> in admin pages causing IE Quirks mode?

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I have a blog where the front end works fine in all major browsers (ie7+). Unfortunately the back end doesn't work n IE8, as the browser is put into 'Quirks mode'. The vast majority of my contributors will be using IE8, so it has to work on IE8. I think IE is activating Quirks mode due to the stylesheet being called before the doctype declaration.

I have another blog which does work in IE8 as well (no Quirks mode), and the only difference I can tell in the source code is the declaration of a stylesheet before the doctype.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this is happening, or if anyone knows how to change the header of the back end/admin of wordpress so I can move/delete the stylesheet declaration.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Can you post some code. Your header file should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't think the problem is in the Theme because when I change the to the standard one the problem is still there in the admin pages. I have also re-installed wordpress twice. What file would you like me to post? I havn't modified any of the core wordpress files.

Comment: Hhmm. Have you got any plugins installed? Is it your main stylesheet that's being added in the wrong place? What's the site?

Comment: The problem was caused by a plugin called WP Mailto Links (http://www.freelancephp.net/en/wp-mailto-links-plugin-2/). I'll email the author and let him know. Does anybody have any recommendations for a similar plugin. It was trying to add a stylesheet that didn't exist for some reason? 

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Cool. It's always a good idea to disable all your plugins when you have a problem as it's generally what's causing it. Specially if you've ruled out the theme.

Comment: Yeh I just thought I'd give that a go after you said about the plugins being installed. It turns out the plugin hasn't been tested in the lastest version of Wordpress. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a plugin called WP Mailto Links (freelancephp.net/en/wp-mailto-links-plugin-2). I disabled all the plugins and went through them one by one and by a process of elimination I managed to identify the cause of the problem and disable to plugin.